# Remove project from SCM in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, version-control

I have an iphone project on a mac.  I set up an SCM repository and then ignored it for a while.  Now I've decided to back up my source to my main PC and do source control there. I'm finding that the SCM wants to roll back my changes seemingly at random.

How can I kill SCM in Xcode on the mac?  I need to tell it to leave my source files alone.  Nothing is worse than making changes and having your changes replaced.

I work alone, but have about 10 projects in source control on the pc.

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: Which SCM are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your using Xcode: As long as you have all your files (and another back up) you can go to preferences, scm, and then just remove the repository.

Comment: @mydogisbox It's now in Organizer | Repositories

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove svn from folder manually

check the .svn folder is deleted from your project
its in very directory and sub directory