# Using Source Code on duplicated project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a project that I want to use 95% of in another project.  I created a new projecst (different name, different location) and added the .h and .m files (kept the same names) from the old project that I wanted.  No those .h and .m files are all reflecting M, A and U based on the original source control.  I thought maybe the Name could be changed, but that shows up as an A in the source control.

Any ideas of how to disable source control for this project without effecting the original project svn.

Comment: You can remove your project from SCM in xcode:

[remove project from SCM in xcode][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836856/remove-project-from-scm-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you still want to use SCM, you can branch or fork the original code, and then open the new branch/form in Xcode.

Comment: OK. Can you direct me to a document on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Sure. http://blog.evanweaver.com/2007/08/15/svn-branching-best-practices-in-practice/ seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Branching isn't going to work.  IS there not a way to disconnect SVN from a project?  It appears that the SVN links all files from duplicated projects into one source control.  How do I get around this?

Comment: One "disconnects" code from SVN by deleting all the .svn folders; there is one in each folder of your code. There are scripts for doing this in one fell swoop. There *should* be an svn command to do it, but you can't always get what you want.